# How to make clang-format not remove a space between override and empty curly braces?

Tags: c++, formatting, clang-format

clang-format keeps formatting this code:

```
class Child : public Parent {
 public:
    void firstMethod() override { someFunction(*this); }
    void secondMethod() override {};
};
```

Into this:

```
class Child : public Parent {
 public:
    void firstMethod() override { someFunction(*this); }
    void secondMethod() override{};
};
```

Which parameter should I change so that clang-format doesn't remove a space between override and empty curly braces? I tried to manipulate various parameters but I got the same result every time.

Comment: `$ clang-format whatever` and, right after `$ sed -i 's/override{/override {/' *.cpp`

Comment: @pmg • I like that, it's the expedient approach (and I may use that for my own clang-format purposes).  "We'll fix it in post."  The alternative is:  clang-format is open source.  Add your formatting feature.  Why spend 2 minutes with a **sed** solution, when you could spend months understanding and adding a feature to **clang-format**?

Comment: [OT]: `;` is unneeded after `{}`.